# Format of JSON data

Tags: json, entity-framework, webmethod

I try to get data in json format like this

```
[{month: 'July',data: [14]}, {month: 'June', data: [3]}, {month: 'May', data: [4]  }]
```

I try this code

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string summarydata()
    {

        try
        {
            TrackDataEntities1 sd = new TrackDataEntities1();
            var data = new TrackDataEntities1().spsumdata()
            .Select(s => new { month = s.Month, data = new int[] { s.data.Value } }).ToArray();

            return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

    }
```

When i check console data is like this

```
[{"month":"July","data":[14]},{"month":"June","data":[3]},{"month":"May","data":[4]}]
```

whereas i want like this

```
[{month: 'July',data: [14]}, {month: 'June', data: [3]}, {month: 'May', data: [4]  }]
```

Comment: The result your getting is the correct JSON format. What you're after is not JSON.

Comment: i am trying to display that json data in high-chart link: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-labels/

Comment: beacuse in that jsfiddle data in series display like this name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        },

Comment: Doesn't matter as far as Javascript is concerned. You should be able to plug in the standard JSON that is being generated without any problem.

Comment: ok thanku for info

Answer (score 0):

A json attribute or string is always defined with double quotes, only doubles, ints or any other non-string value hasn't quotes.